# find method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, async-await

I make find method on users array but selectedUserId = undefined
How can I execute this method necessarily after the async function so that the selectedUserId is not undefined?

```
function App() { 
const [selectedUserId, setSelectedUserId] = useState(null)
const [users,setUsers] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
console.log(users)

useAsyncEffect(async () => {
  setLoading(true)
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  const data = await res.json()
  setUsers(data)
  setLoading(false)
 }, [])

 const selectedUser = users.find(u => u.id === selectedUserId)
 console.log(selectedUser)

 const onUserClick = (userId) => {
  setSelectedUserId(userId)
}

if(loading) {
  return <img src={preloader} alt="preloader"/>
} 

return (
  <div>
  { !selectedUser ? <ListUsers users={users} onUserClick={onUserClick} /> : <Profile user= 
  {selectedUser}  />
  }
  </div>
 )
 }
```

Comment: In this case, it feels like `selectedUser` may be completely avoided. Instead of `<Profile user={selectedUser} />` try: `<Profile user={users.find(u => u.id === selectedUserId)} />`. And, instead of `{ !selectedUser ? ..` try `{ !selectedUserId ? ..`.

Comment: Thanks man, this actually works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`useEffect()` hook will be called after rendering / component update.
so, on First time the `users` value will be empty array.

so, the selectedUser value will be undefined.
Wrap it in another useEffect will work.